# Looking for a text by Yosef Perl (a parodist of Rebbe Nachman)

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe, misnaged

Yosef Perl was a satirist, and is often described as a maskil. A vigorous opponent of hasidim in particular, he was active in the middle of the 19th century when the stories of Rebbe Nachman and *Shivchei haBesht* were first published. His most famous work is *Megaleh Temirin* (1819), which he published under a pseudonym.

His first satirical work was not published during his lifetime, and I've been unable to even find what it was called. It was a parody of Rebbe Nachman's stories, written in the same style (in a combination of Hebrew and Yiddish), providing a comic conclusion to one story that ended suddenly in the original, and inventing another story from whole cloth. Perl's style in all of his writings was to ridicule hasidim by way of imitation, and I would very much like to see an example of this.

If anybody here is familiar with maskilic literature and could recommend to me where I might find more information about Yosef Perl, that would be great. Ideally, I would love to see a copy of this particular text (his parody of Rebbe Nachman's stories). I understand that it's almost certainly not for sale, but if there is a published version in a library somewhere, I should be able to get it through an interlibrary loan. (And, if not, maybe one day take a vacation...)

From what I understand, Perl had a negligible impact upon the subsequent history of maskilic literature. He was a frum Jew, and is probably better classed together with misnagdim than maskilim, but for the fact that he also published in German and availed himself of the writings of other wordly, cosmopolitan Jews (like Menachem Mendel Lefin, for example).

Comment: Is this on topic? Is this about Judaism or Letzanism?

Comment: @user6591, Yosef Perl was Jewish. His book was written in Hebrew and Yiddish. It relates directly to social movements of some significance that existed in the Jewish world in the 19th century. I think it's very much on topic. (And parody is a very well-established genre in Jewish writing, even if you don't approve of the object of it here.)

Comment: Is J for J on topic here? It's by Jews, for Jews, and undermines what Jews believe in. Just like a Jewish Letz mocking religious Jews to a Jewish audience.

Comment: @user6591 - that's a question for Meta. (I would argue no, it's not appropriate). It's also totally different. There's more than one type of Judaism. If the only type of Judaism that had ever existed was hasidic Judaism, maybe you'd have a point. But misnagdim are Jews too :) And Yosef Perl wasn't mocking religious Jews, he was mocking *some* religious Jews. He was also religious, as I noted in the question.

Comment: I would agree that mocking a movement for a religious reason would be on topic. But I don't think these types of mockeries  were done lisheim shomaim, in order to preserve what the author thought was authentic Judaism. It was done lisheim letzanus. Just my 2 cents. I'm not downvoting. Just raising a point.

Comment: Do you mean: מעשיות ואיגרות, מצדיקים אמיתיים ומאנשי שלומנו?

Comment: @Loewian - YES!! That looks like it! Where did you find it? Your Googling skills are clearly superior to my own :) Or did you already know of it?

Comment: http://www.worldcat.org/title/maasiyot-ve-igrot-mi-tsadikim-amitiyim-ume-anshe-shelomenu/oclc/19147235

Comment: I think I used "joseph perl satirical Nachman" and got http://asfaculty.syr.edu/pages/rel/_PDFs-others/_kfrieden/Joseph%20Perls%20Escape%20From%20Biblical%20Epigonism.pdf which mentions it.  I think it's also in his hebrew wikipedia page.

Comment: you might also want to try this guy: http://forward.com/culture/books/307727/the-sephardic-bibliophile-of-brooklyn/

Comment: http://www.findabook.co.il/bookDetail.aspx?title=%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA+++%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99+%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95&book_id=338017

Comment: @Loewian Good job.  You should post this as the answer.

Comment: @user6591 For better or worse many Jews believe(d) making fun of Chasidim to be an important Judaism activity. Seeking information about that practice seems quite on topic.

Comment: @Double perhaps a satire by a talmid chacham against what he thought was a threat to Judaism would be on topic (as I mentioned in a different comment.) A play by a layman who can possibly be identified as a mosser according to his wiki page should not be any more on topic than any random miyodea user rambling against certain groups of Jews.

Comment: @use Why must someone be a Torah scholar to do a mitzva?

Comment: If it is an act which is hard to discern whether it is a mitzvah or an aveira it takes a Torah scholar to do. If the act was done with bad intentions but happened to be allowed unbeknown to the offender, he still needs a kapara. This is all theoretical as I am not going to agree with you that this is a mitzvah. Much the same as you wouldn't agree a chassid's writings making fun of maskilim is a mitzvah and belongs on this site.

Comment: @user6591 I don't need you to agree it's a Mitzva. I never even claimed that myself. I just said some Jews (among them great scholars) have held as much.

Comment: @user6591 - I also don't think that it's a mitzva, but I don't think this site is only about mitzvot. By analogy (and lehavdil), Breslov hasidim were violently persecuted for many years *by other hasidim*. More recently, there was a great deal of violence between Satmar and Belz hasidim in New York. The fact that these actions are deplorable doesn't mean they didn't happen, and the fact that the perpetrators were frum yidden makes their actions relevant (IMHO) to this site. Misnagdic parodies of hasidic literature are a part of our literary history - as much as the hasidic literature itself.

Comment: @Shimon and 100 years from now those deplorable acts will be seen as part of our history.

Comment: Looks like it's discussed in this book https://www.academia.edu/5478023/Imagined_Hasidism_The_Anti-Hasidic_Writings_of_Joseph_Perl_Jerusalem_Mossad_Bialik_2013_316_pp._Hebrew_

Answer (score 1):

The text that you are looking for is [referred to](http://www.worldcat.org/title/maasiyot-ve-igrot-mi-tsadikim-amitiyim-ume-anshe-shelomenu/oclc/19147235) by @Loewian in the comments. However, it should be noted that some strongly doubt the ascription of this book to [Joseph Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Perl); most notably was the bibliographer A.M. Habermann (Kvuzei Yachad 143ff.). One of the main reasons for the skeptics' doubt is because Perl was *anti-Yiddish*, while this book incorporates Yiddish into its text (as noted by OP). However it may be argued that Perl may have made an exception as alluded to at the end of his intro. to his Megaleh Temirin [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=czo_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT7#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Another book that was posthumously printed and ascribed to Perl is the collection of [Yiddish letters](http://www.rachelnet.net/media/medem/livres/000054170.pdf). This book too is a subject of dispute (Habermann, loc. cit.).

Comment: Comments might get deleted.  You should move anything important into the body of the answer.

Comment: This isn't an answer - it's a comment, which refers to another comment, which was the actual answer. I'm confused. Why don't you move Loewian's comment into this so that it contains an answer to my question? Also, Perl's antipathy towards Yiddish is the very reason that he employed it here. As mentioned, it's a parody.

Comment: @ShimonbM Honestly, I just don't know how to move a comment into an answer. By all means, you can. Though now I'm confused too: you asked where you can locate a certain text. I then referenced a link to it which was provided by Loewian. I further enhanced the answer by providing information about the text in question since your whole q. revolves around a point of contention - something you neglected to mention. Finally, I furnished you with a source for your query on how "[you] might find more information about Yosef Perl". So how is this *not* an answer?